# How can I apply cat (UNIX) command individually, to all files in a folder?

Tags: command-line, unix, batch, concatenation

Here's the situation:

My file A.csv needs to be concatenated individually with all the other *.csv's in the folder and each of the outputs needs to have the same name as the particular *.csv.

How can I do this at the terminal? I have to do this 50 times and the other csv's have no ordered naming convention so typing manually is a pain.

The data is sensitive so I can't fool around with checking if 
cat A.csv *csv >*.csv works. (I'm guessing it won't)

Comment: FYI `>` will overwrite the file with the terminal output. `>>` will append the terminal output to the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a for-loop in `bash`.  You can make yourself a harmless test first:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.csv; do
    if [ "$f" != 'A.csv' ]; then
        echo cat A.csv "$f" \> "$f.new"
    fi
done
```

This allows you to see what will be executed but not actually execute it.

Notice that I have called the output file `$f.new`.  You can't guarantee that the `cat` will be performed before the shell starts overwriting the file.  So I recommend you do this, or even better write the files into another directory:

```
mkdir combined
for f in *.csv; do
    if [ "$f" != 'A.csv' ]; then
        echo cat A.csv $f \> "combined/$f"
    fi
done
```

And of course, once you're happy, remove the echo (and the escaped `>` character):

```
cat A.csv "$f" > "combined/$f"
```

Comment: If you want to handle spaces properly all you have to do is double-quote your variables, simple as that :)